# Where Store SQL Server credentials on Windows Client to Access SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, security

I have a Windows service running under a local system account on all company clients. But my service needs to access SQL Server 2008 R2 which is on a central SQL Server instance.

My problem is how to securely store the login credentials for the SQL Server connection and access them with C#. Or is there another opportunity to connect to SQL Server?

What are best practices for such a scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to run the Windows Service under a dedicated domain account. This way username and password would not need to be stored on the local computer at all. You could use integrated security instead and grant SQL Server access to that domain account.

If that's not an option for you, you will need to encrypt the sensitive data in your configuration file. You might want to take a look at [`SectionInformation.ProtectSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: No Running the Service under dedicated Service Account is no Option atm. The I will have a Look on SectionInformation thx

Comment: I have read a Bit about the SectionInformation Method and the Protection is machine / Computer dependent and That don't work in my cenario, the Service is deloyed on all Company Computers